# jboss-modules.jar in bootclasspath cause ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jboss, wildfly

When I use `JAVA_OPTS` with `-Xbootclasspath/a:$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar` in Java 11,

```
15:04:41,952 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:403)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.wildfly.extension.undertow
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:100)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_16.java:240)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.readElement(StandaloneXml_16.java:140)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:144)
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.load(DeferredExtensionContext.java:92)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.controller.CommonUnaryRequirement.<clinit>(CommonUnaryRequirement.java:41)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ApplicationSecurityDomainSingleSignOnDefinition$Attribute.<clinit>(ApplicationSecurityDomainSingleSignOnDefinition.java:65)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.UndertowSubsystemParser_9_0.<init>(UndertowSubsystemParser_9_0.java:357)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionRegistry$ExtensionParsingContextImpl.attemptCurrentParserInitialization(ExtensionRegistry.java:508)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionRegistry$ExtensionParsingContextImpl.access$200(ExtensionRegistry.java:434)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionRegistry.initializeParsers(ExtensionRegistry.java:249)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.loadModule(DeferredExtensionContext.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext.access$000(DeferredExtensionContext.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:74)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.DeferredExtensionContext$1.call(DeferredExtensionContext.java:71)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource from [Module "org.jboss.as.clustering.common" version 23.0.0.Final from local module loader @66e827a8 (finder: local module finder @5bb911c1 (roots: D:\Runtime\wildfly-23.0.0.Final\modules,D:\Runtime\wildfly-23.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: What is the reason you're using the boot class path?

Comment: Because of Pinpoint2 agent

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using? You definitely should not have JBoss Modules on the boot class path.

Comment: WildFly 21,22,23 have the same problem

Comment: You can't have jboss-modules on the boot class path. With WildFly 21 you can set the agent in the `MODULE_OPTS` instead of the `JAVA_OPTS` which would be preferred. If you could share your `standalone.conf` I can help there.

Comment: If use module_opts, Pinpoint agent will cause "Invalid pinpoint-bootstrap.jar"   if (Object.class.getClassLoader() != PinpointBootStrap.class.getClassLoader()) {
      logger.warn("Invalid pinpoint-bootstrap.jar:" + agentArgs);
      return;
    }

Comment: Given that it's a warning, does it break anything? If the agent does not do any logging, you could set the agent itself in the `JAVA_OPTS` instead of the `MODULE_OPTS`.